# How to include cyrillic letters in the bibliography using \cyrchar ... e.g. \cyrsdsc (ҫ)

Tags: bibtex, cyrillic

I am stuck with a very restricting LaTeX template, am forced to use bibtex and cannot figure out how to get the cyrillic letter ҫ in my bibliography render correctly.

The letter is represented by `\cyrchar\cyrsdsc` in the bibliography file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{Karakoc,
    title = {Some imaginary title},
    author = {Karako\cyrchar\cyrsdsc, F.},
    year = {2024},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    Citing~\cite{Karakoc}

    \bibliography{bibliography}{}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How come the name has just *one* Cyrillic character? Where did you get the citation from? From what I see with Google, Karakoç is a Turkish name.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijsolstr.2016.05.002 
I loaded their RIS-file into zotero and thex exported using BetterBibtex, but the bibtex-file they provide also contains the cyrillic letter.

Comment: That's clearly wrong. The name has ç.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will fix it in my literature database then and ask the journal to fix it in theirs.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822312004606#! has ç

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to declare the character's encoding.

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Karakoc,
    title = {Some imaginary title},
    author = {Karako\cyrsdsc, F.},
    year = {2024},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[X2,T1]{fontenc} % or OT1 instead of T1

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrsdsc}{X2}

\begin{document}

Citing~\cite{Karakoc}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, this seems to be a blunder by Elsevier, because it makes little sense that a name has a single Cyrillic character. The name in question seems to be Turkish and so it should have `ç`.

Answer (score 0):

This works: enable russian as a secondary language in babel and then define the macro
`\newcommand{\cyrchar}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\newcommand{\cyrchar}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{Karakoc,
    title = {Some imaginary title},
    author = {Karako\cyrchar\cyrsdsc, F.},
    year = {2024},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    Citing~\cite{Karakoc}

    \bibliography{bibliography}{}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```